# winsdor register a generic type with constructor parameter

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

i have somthing like this

```
 MyRepository<T> : IRepository<T> {

  public MyRepository(string cs){
   ....
```

}

so i need to register in winsdor this generic type and give him a parameter

i've been trying to do this like so :

```
Type t = typeof(IRepository<>);
Type t1 = typeof(Repository<>);
Hashtable props = new Hashtable(); 
props.Add("cs", "myconnstring");
container.AddComponentWithProperties("key1", t, t1, props);
```

and i get the following error

Can't create component 'key1' as it has dependencies to be satisfied. 
key1 is waiting for the following dependencies:

Keys (components with specific keys)
- cs which was not registered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>))
   .ImplementedBy(typeof(MyRepository<>))
   .Parameters(Parameter.ForKey("cs").Eq("myconnstring"));
```

Check out the [fluent registration wiki](http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Fluent+Registration+API) for more information.

Comment: thnx man it worked fine, i just put the value of cs inside Eq(value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();


        container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ICustomGenericRepository<>))
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(CustomGenericRepository<>))
        .LifeStyle.Transient);
```